# Browser does not display Typescript source map

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

I use Meteor with Typescript.
I can't see any sourcemap in the ressource tab. All I have when I select a .ts file is: `module.exports = require("./index.js");`
[image]

My typescript configuration is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "client/**/*.ts",
    "imports/**/*.ts",
    "server/**/*.ts",
    "typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I use Barbatus package to compile typescript:

```
barbatus:typescript@0.4.0
barbatus:typescript-compiler@0.7.0
barbatus:typescript-runtime@0.1.2
```

And my environment config is:

```
METEOR@1.4.0.1
node v4.2.3
```